# How to get new messages from telegram channel (not group) using python?

Tags: python, telegram

Is there any way to get NEW messages from telegram channel using Python?
As simple as it can be possible?

I'm trying to use:

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events, sync

# These example values won't work. You must get your own api_id and
# api_hash from https://my.telegram.org, under API Development.
api_id = "505050"
api_hash = "hashcodehere"
client = TelegramClient('anon', api_id, api_hash)


async def main():
    # You can print the message history of any chat:
    async for message in client.iter_messages('DEXTNewPairsPolygon',12):
        print(message.sender.username, message.text)
        print('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

with client:
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

It get me a lot's of errors.

[image]

Maybe is there any EASYEST way to get new latest messages from any telegramm channel? Some kind of listening channel and output messages with print? Maybe new/better libs, than "telethon"?
**I need working example**

I am also not admin of this channel, I only need get new messages to get from them information.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this package which I use:- https://pypi.org/project/python-telegram/

Otherwise using the package you are you could do this:

```py
# get the channel entity
entity = client.get_entity(channel)

# get the channel messages
messages = client(functions.messages.GetHistoryRequest(
    peer=entity,
    limit=10,  # replace with the number of messages you want to retrieve
))

# print the new messages
for message in messages.messages:
    print(message.message)
```

You'll need to set up a `session_name` if you want to store your session information. You can also use `events` module to listen for new messages in real time.